# Find the equation of specific lines

Tags: geometry

We are given two points $A(1, 2)$ and $B(3, -1)$. Find the equation of the lines that pass through $A$ and are situated at a distance of $2$ from $B$.

Let $d: ax + by + c = 0$ be the equation of the desired lines and $M(x, y)$ a point such that $BM$ is $2$.

Since $ABM$ is a right triangle, we can apply Pitagora's theorem, and therefore we get $AM = 3$.

$$AM = \sqrt{(x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2} = 3$$
$$BM = \sqrt{(x - 3)^2 + (y + 1)^2} = 2$$

By calculating $BM^2 - AM^2$ I got $y = 2x - 2$.

From this point I don't know how I should continue.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How have you found that $AM=3$?  Or $\sqrt{3}$ as in your equation for $x$?

Comment: It's 3, I edited.

Comment: plug y = 2x-2 back into the formula for the length of AM (after you square both of its sides) and solve for x, and then for y. You will find two solutions. This will give you the two possible points M. Then make your line go through A and M - you should find two different lines.

Answer (score 1):

You are searching the lines passing through $A$ and tangent to the circle of center $b$ and radius $2$. One trivial solution is the line $x=1$ , parallel to the $y$ axis and passing thorough $A=(1,2)$ and $M=(1,-1)$.

So, as you have found the distance from $A$ and the point $M$ is $\overline{AM}=3$ and we have also another point $N=(x_N,y_N)$ such that $\overline{AN}=3$, that is the other solution of the system:
$$
\begin{cases}
(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2=9\\
(x-3)^2+(y+1)^2=4
\end{cases}
$$

Note that we can also found the other tangent line noting that:

the circle has equation $ (x-3)^2+(y+1)^2=2$ and the lines through $A$  are represented by: $y-2=m(x-1)$

So the line is tangent to the circle if the the system:
$$
\begin{cases}
(x-3)^2+(y+1)^2=2\\
y-2=m(x-1)
\end{cases}
$$
have only one (double) solution. This is done if the discriminat of the system ( that is an expressin depending on $m$)  is null: $\Delta(m)=0$. Solving this equation we can find the slope $m$ of the tangent line.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment I suggested how you can finish your solution (along the line you started on, which is correct and perfectly fine).

Here is another approach. The conditions mean the line passes through A and is tangent to the circle of radius 2 with center B. You can easily write the equations of the vertical line through A and verify if it is or it isn't at distance 2 from B, so let's now look for non-vertical lines, so we can write the equation as $y = mx+n$. The intersection points of this line and the circle of radius 2 centered at B is given by the set of solutions of $y = mx+n, (x-3)^2 + (y+1)^2=4$. This can be solved by plugging $y$ from the first equation into the second equation; there are at most two solutions for $x$ (a line and a circle meet in at most two points), and the tangency condition is that this quadratic equation for $x$ have a double root, or that its discriminant be $0$. This gives a quadratic condition for $m,n$, and the condition that the line pass through $A$ gives a linear equation for $m, n$. Solve for $m, n.$

Answer (score 0):

the line is given by $$ax+by+c=0$$ and passes through $$A(1,2)$$ this gives us:
$$a+2b+c=0$$ and our line is now given by $$ax+by-a-2b=0$$ which has the Hessian form of $$\frac{ax+by-a-2b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=0$$ plugging $$x=3$$,$$y=-1$$ in the equation above you have to solve the equation
$$\frac{|2a-3b|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=2$$